# Oracle Employee constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I'm still new in SQL and I'm kinda stuck. Here's my script :

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
         (SSN                 NUMBER          NOT NULL,
          FNAME               VARCHAR(8)     ,
          MINIT               VARCHAR(1)     ,
          LNAME               VARCHAR(7)     ,              
          BDATE               DATE           ,
          SEX                 VARCHAR(1)     ,
          SALARY              NUMBER(8,2)    ,
          SUPERSSN            NUMBER         ,
          DNO                 NUMBER(2)      ,
CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY (SSN),
CONSTRAINT Employee_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (SUPERSSN) REFERENCES Employee(SSN));

INSERT INTO Employee  (SSN, FNAME, MINIT, LNAME, BDATE, SEX, SALARY, SUPERSSN, DNO)
VALUES  (123456789, 'John', 'B', 'Smith', '09-JAN-55', 'M', '30000', '333445555', '5');

COMMIT;
DESC Employee
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a constraint for SUPERSSN > SSN but it always gives me  integrity constraint violated - parent key not found 
When i remove CONSTRAINT Employee_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (SUPERSSN) REFERENCES Employee(SSN), it works perfectly.

But, if I keep it and remove the insert into employee script instead, it also works fine. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I use Oracle.

Comment: You need to _first_ insert an employee with the SSN you are referencing. That's the whole point of a foreign key: ensure that you insert a value that _already_ exists

Comment: So you are saying that i need to insert the value first,then add the constraint after?

Comment: No, you need to first insert a an employee with the SSN=333445555 before you can insert an employee that uses that as the SUPERSSN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to add data on column that its a foreign key you have to make sure it is parent has data, for example the table `SUPERSSN` doesn't contain `SSN` 123456789 .

Insert a rescord where SSN = 123456789 and it will work.

I'll give you an example about 2 tables.

> table `FoodMarket` contain `Id` and `employer`
>
> And table `sandwich` contains column `Id` , `Name` and `DateCreated`

Now logically you cannot have a sandwich if it doesn't exist in the market, correct ? So we create on this table a foreign key on one column id

```
  alter table Sandwish add CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES FoodMarket(id)
```

So if you want to insert a new sandwich, let's say hamburger, its id should exist in the market, if you insert in the sandwich table an in id = 10 but this value = 10 doesn't exist in the market, it will raise error, you should add **first** id 10 in the `market` to let you insert `id =10` in table sandwiches.

Comment: Do I insert that after after I inset into employee values or before?

Comment: As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, you should insert an employee with SSN, let me explain to you how foriegn key works. lets say there is a car that doesnt belong to anyone, you cannot register it or drive it or sell it because it doesnt belong to anyone(it doesnt have a parent). if this car belongs to you then you are the parent . so when people ask this car for whom ( its foriegn key) , its for parent jessica . get it ? @JessicaChu

Comment: Ya I know but i'm still new in SQL, so i create the table that has that data first then put constraint after? can you show me the complete script please >.<